# The difference of two charges

Tags: measure-theory

Definition in Bartle:

If $\mathcal{X}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of a set $X$, then a real-valued function $\lambda$ defined on $\mathcal{X}$ is said to be a charge in case $\lambda(\phi)=0$ and $\lambda$ is countably additive in the sense that if $\{E_n\}$ is a disjoint sequence of sets in $\mathcal{X}$, then

$$\lambda\left(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda(E_n).$$

Then the sentence "It is clear that the difference of two charges is a charge."

OK, so I try to show that this last sentence is true. Let $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ be charges. Then:

$$(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\phi)
=\lambda_1(\phi)-\lambda_2(\phi)
=0-0
=0$$

Secondly, let $\{E_n\}$ be a disjoint sequence of sets in $\mathcal{X}$. Then:

$$\begin{align*}
(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)
&=\lambda_1(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)-\lambda_2(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_1(E_n)-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_2(E_n)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\lambda_1(E_n)-\lambda_2(E_n)\right]
\end{align*}$$

However, I have no idea how to justify my last step. I do know that if two series converge, that is, if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n=A$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n=B$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n-b_n]=A-B$. That is,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[a_n-b_n]=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$$

However, in the last step of the argument above on the difference of two charges, I don't know that those series converge.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Since you can rearrange the sequence of disjoint measurable sets $(E_n)$ without changing its union, $\sigma$-additivity implies absolute convergence of $(\lambda_1(E_n))$ and $(\lambda_2(E_n))$ and you can rearrange them however you like.